# Alert Dialog (List) custom rows for items

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to popup a list backed by a string array, using the following code:

```
public void gameDialog(Activity activity) {
        
    

        TextView title = new TextView(activity);
        title.setText("Click a number to make a call");
        title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        title.setTextSize(20);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setCustomTitle(title);
        //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_36);

    //  builder.setMessage(""+arrayPhones);

        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setItems(arrayPhones,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {



            }

        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
        
        
        TextView messageText = (TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //  messageText.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
```

I get a null pointer when I try to set attributes to messageText. I want to customize the rows of above list by placing text in center and a different font color. Any hints where I am wrong?

### Here is the logCat:

```
01-31 20:55:06.328: E/InputEventReceiver(25240): Exception dispatching input event.
01-31 20:55:06.328: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3.showAlert(Fragment1_3.java:347)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3$1.onTouch(Fragment1_3.java:189)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7138)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2238)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1935)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1938)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1392)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2408)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7323)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3560)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4637)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4597)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:140)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-31 20:55:06.339: E/MessageQueue-JNI(25240):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 20:55:06.339: D/AndroidRuntime(25240): Shutting down VM
01-31 20:55:06.340: W/dalvikvm(25240): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f67908)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3.showAlert(Fragment1_3.java:347)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.exa.birthdayrem.Fragment1_3$1.onTouch(Fragment1_3.java:189)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7138)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2238)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1935)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2244)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1907)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1938)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1392)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2408)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1886)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7323)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3560)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3490)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4637)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4597)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4749)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:140)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-31 20:55:06.346: E/AndroidRuntime(25240):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat output with stacktrace.

Comment: android.R.id.message it's not in the view of alert dialog

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it to be a Dialog?

You could create a new Activity and adding the dialog theme. If you are working for devices prior to 4.0 you will have to do the following:

Create a folder res/values-v11 (this will work for API 11+) and after doing so, add a file called `styles.xml`. In this file type the following:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_activity_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Then in your `styles.xml` located in your  in /res/values folder add this lines:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_activity_theme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

and then, apply it to your application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    ...
    <android:theme="@style/my_activity_theme"/>

</activity
```

This way you will be able to have a floating activity. I haven't tested it but I think it is worth trying.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your code AlertDialog has not initialized yet so it gives you nullpointer.Initialize your AlertDialog  through the create() method of Builder. Something like:

```
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

And also you have not used any view here. In your method parameter take one view with the activity and initialize your view components through this not through alert.

```
public void gameDialog(Activity activity, View view) {
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
}
```

And pass the parent layout which holds the textview through your parameter.

Comment: what is R.id.message .. where is its parent layout ??